# Python - convert binary mask to polygon

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, polygon, mask

Given a simple binary mask (e.g. the boundary of a rectangle).

[image: binary mask]

How can I use a polygon to get the x-y coordinates?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
coords = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))
```

However, this approach generates a filled object and not the desired boundary.

```
plt.plot(coords[:, 1], coords[:,0])
```

[image: unwanted output]

Basically, I want a list of x-y coordinates of the white pixels to use this list to re-draw the rectangle (not filled).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.column_stack()` + `np.where()`. The idea is to determine the white pixels in the binary image then order then in corresponding `(x, y)` order

```
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(image > 0))
```

---

Another way is to find the coordinates of the bounding rectangle using OpenCV's `cv2.boundingRect()`. This will give you the width, height, and top-left `(x,y)` coordinates. Here's an example finding the coordinates then drawing the polygon onto a blank mask

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(image)
mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])
cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks nathancy. I tried your solution but got the same output result for 'coord'. Could you please specify what you mean by order the (x,y) coords?

Comment: I meant obtain the (x,y) coordinates for the polygon. Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, can you elaborate on what you mean by "not the desired boundary". Maybe add an expected output image

Comment: I edited the original post with the wrong output. The expected output image should be the same as the original output (the boundary of a rectangle - not filled). I hope this helps.

Comment: Check the update, you can find the bounding rectangle coordinates then use this to draw it on another image

Answer (score 7):

Using `cv2.findContours` works both for complex shapes and multiple objects. `Polygons` list contains `coords` lists each looking like this [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ...].

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
polygons = []

for obj in contours:
    coords = []
        
    for point in obj:
        coords.append(int(point[0][0]))
        coords.append(int(point[0][1]))

    polygons.append(coords)
```

Comment: I like this solution but the input to the function is a binary mask but if my image has multiple classes and I know the pallette for each class, then how would I go about that.

Comment: I can think of two ways to go about it. 1. You can find a way to assign each polygon its according class (the function should recognize all the classes) based on average pixel value or their coordinates. 2. You can iterate through the classes and generate binary mask for each of them, then run the function. One way to do that would be by numpy.where()

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the square like an object and acess its properties with `skimage.measure.regionprops` function.

I strongly advices to take a look at the documentation as its a very usefull function in many cases:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

Also, there is `skimage.measure.regionprops_table` wich gives you a dictionarie to covert to a pandas dataframe.

Here's my solution:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.measure import regionprops_table
from pandas import DataFrame

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rectangle = imread('rectangle_img.png')    
props_rect = DataFrame(regionprops_table(rectangle, properties=['coords']))

new_img = np.zeros((rectangle.shape[0], rectangle.shape[1]))

for point in props_rect['coords'][0]:

    new_img[point[0], point[1]] = 1


plt.imshow(new_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
polygons = [np.array(polygon).squeeze() for polygon in contours]
```

`polygons` is a `list` with `arrays` of shape `N, 2`, where `N` corresponds to the number of points and `2` corresponds to `x` and `y` coordinates